# Javascript if (window.location.href) adding two urls

Tags: javascript, html, css, if-statement

Very simple question but can't find the answer. Can you put two url's inside

```
 if (window.location.href
```

here is mine:

```
if (window.location.href == 'http://example.example.com/support/default.asp') {
}
```

I need to add a second link... so i only want a div to load from that page and one more page.

Comment: Use or (`||`) operator, eh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be as simples as

```
if (window.location.href == 'http://example.example.com/support/default.asp' ||
    window.location.href == 'http://secondurl.com') {
}
```

unless I misunderstood the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use || (or) in if loop.

```
if (window.location.href == 'http://example.example.com/support/default.asp' 
|| window.location.href == 'http://example2.com') {
}
```